# Comparing key-value pairs in Python

Tags: python, loops, dictionary, key-value

I have something like this

```
a = [{'name': 'John', 'supporterId': 1}, {'name': 'Paul', 'supporterId': 2}]
b = [{'dependent': 'Erick','supporterId': 2}, {'dependent': 'Anna', 'supporterId': 2}, {'dependent': 'George','supporterId': 13}]
```

and I need to check if the `supporterId` between `a` and `b` are equal and if so put the `name_dependent` inside the corresponding `supporterId` in `a` so for example the output to this should be:

```
c = [{'name': 'John', 'supporterId': 1}, {'name': 'Paul', 'supporterId': 2, 'dependent': [Erick, Anna]}]
```

I have tried many for loops inside another but it doesn't seem to work...

Answer (score 0):

The following should work:

```py
from collections import defaultdict

a = [{'name': 'John', 'supporterId': 1}, {'name': 'Paul', 'supporterId': 2}]
b = [{'dependent': 'Erick','supporterId': 2}, {'dependent': 'Anna', 'supporterId': 2}, {'dependent': 'George','supporterId': 13}]

dependents = defaultdict(list)
for x in b:
    dependents[x['supporterId']].append(x['dependent'])

def gen_c_item(x):
    if x['supporterId'] in dependents:
        return {**x, 'dependent': dependents[x['supporterId']]}
    return x

c = [gen_c_item(x) for x in a]
```

This results in `c` being:

```py
{'name': 'John', 'supporterId': 1}, {'name': 'Paul', 'supporterId': 2, 'dependent': ['Erick', 'Anna']}]
```

It builds a dict that maps from each supporter ID in `b` to a list of the names of the dependents, then uses that dict to construct `c` efficiently.

Comment: Thats 100% right but now that I'm thinking can I have the output in c like: data: [{name_dependent: Erick}, name_dependente: Anna] other than they together in a single key-value pair?

Comment: If you'd like a different output than what your question originally asked for, you should post a new question.

Answer (score 0):

We can do the following steps to achieve the desired result:

```
a = [{'name': 'John', 'supporterId': 1}, {'name': 'Paul', 'supporterId': 2}]
b = [{'dependent': 'Erick', 'supporterId': 2}, {'dependent': 'Anna', 'supporterId': 2},
     {'dependent': 'George', 'supporterId': 13}]

# Create a dictionary based on suppoertedId as key and whole object as value
by_id = {supporter['supporterId']: supporter for supporter in a}

# Iterate over b
for dependent in b:
    # Check if the dictionary has a object for the current supporterId from b
    if dependent['supporterId'] in by_id:
        # Update the depended list
        by_id[dependent['supporterId']].setdefault('dependent', []).append(dependent['dependent'])

# Get the values from the dictionary
c = list(by_id.values())
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I got this, not the cleanest solution, but gets the job done

> Blockquote
> def pair(supporters, dependents):

```
pairs = []
dependentsToPair = {}

for supporter in supporters:
    dependentsToPair[supporter['supporterId']] = []
    for dependent in dependents:
        if supporter['supporterId'] == dependent['supporterId']:
            dependentsToPair[supporter['supporterId']].append(dependent)

    if dependentsToPair[supporter['supporterId']] != []:
        supporter['dependents'] = dependentsToPair[supporter['supporterId']]
    pairs.append(supporter)

return pairs
```

the whole thing is a function but I can't get it to show here